# Delete dynamic block and keep right count order

Tags: jquery, arrays, dynamic, block

I have a block that I can add dynamically as many times as I want. Here's the code:

```
// Add / delete trainings
var trainingBlock = $('.rbTrainingPlacesBlock');
var countTraining = $('div.rbTrainingPlacesBlock div.rbTrainingAddedPlace').size() + 1;

// Add block button
$('#addTrainingPlace').live('click', function () {
   $('<div class="rbTrainingAddedPlace">/* Some code here */</div>').appendTo(trainingBlock);
   countTraining++;
   return false;
});

// Delete button
$('#deleteTrainingPlace').live('click', function () {
   if (countTraining > 2) {
      $(this).parents('div.rbTrainingAddedPlace').remove();
      countTraining--;
   }
   return false;
});
```

This part works perfectly, but when I add block I have this counter thing adding it to names of input fields, like:

```
<input type="text" name="input[1]">
<input type="text" name="input[2]">
<input type="text" name="input[3]">
```

And so on. But when I delete it, I need to keep the right order. For example with my code, when I delete input2 it will be like this:

```
<input type="text" name="input[1]">
<input type="text" name="input[3]">
```

And I need to change 3 to 2. So the order is right.

What do I need to change in delete button code to make it working?

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alexchizhov/Xq4j9/

Comment: I would take the [n] out from the input name. Calling al inputs with the same name makes the to reach the server as an array, getting them as input[0], input[1]...

Comment: I need to get this array later and work with it, thats why i use [n].

Comment: can't you use: $(input[name=input]) instead?

Comment: where exactly do you want me to use it?

Comment: later, where you need the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the delete button click event write this code:

```
var counter=1;
$('input[name^="input"]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('name','input['+counter+']');
    counter++;
});
```

**UPDATE:**

here's the **[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xq4j9/1/)**

```
$('#deleteTrainingPlace').live('click', function () {
     if (countTraining > 2) {
         $(this).parents('div.rbTrainingAddedPlace').remove();
         countTraining--;
         var counter=1;
        $('input[name^="rbtrainingplace"]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('name','rbtrainingplace['+counter+']');
            $(this).attr('placeholder','rbtrainingplace['+counter+']');
            counter++;
        });
         var counter=1;
        $('input[name^="rbtrainingsubject"]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('name','rbtrainingsubject['+counter+']');
            $(this).attr('placeholder','$rbtrainingsubject['+counter+']');
            counter++;
        });
     }
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: ok, can you please show the whole function for delete button?